# ChartJS for React-Native not rendering after generating APK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-chartjs

We're currently developing a mobile app using react-native.

The App requires to show horizontal bar chart in it, hence we used `KittyCookie/react-native-chartjs` to achieve the same.

The chart works correctly when debugging, but when we generate app APK and open the app, the chart is not rendered. It shows a blank white page.

Ideas appreicated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I need to do was to replace `ChartJS` with `Highcharts`